# Team foundation server in the cloud?

Tags: azure, tfs, cloud, azure-devops

We have been using TFS on our own server for a while. We would like to move it in the cloud.

Is there any good hosted service?

Note: we would like to import all our source and projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Microsoft's list of Hosting Services for Team Foundation Server 2010.
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/hosting

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182647/good-tfs-hosting-provider

Comment: Link of Hosting Services is broken

Comment: Both links are broken :-(

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft provides http://tfs.visualstudio.com/ free Plan  for up to 5 users.

Access to the service will be offered as a benefit—at no additional charge—for paid MSDN subscribers with

•Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN

•Visual Studio Premium with MSDN

•Visual Studio Test Professional with MSDN

Answer (score 0):

As Grant suggested, you can find a list of tfs hosting service providers on Microsoft website. The company I am with, Dynamsoft, is also in the list. I am not sure about other companies' policy. But Dynamsoft offers importing source code and project from VSS to TFS for free.